# How to sort string array first by letter then by number combination?

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell

I can't figure out how to sort a string array first by letter then by number combination. Here is the sample:

```
$a = @('aa101','aa11','ab10','ab9','a111','a22','a01')
```

I would like to see the result after the sorting as follow:

```
a01
a22
a111
aa11
aa101
ab9
ab10
```

Please help me to find out the answer by using PowerShell script.

Comment: The sorting algorithm you describe (sort by first letter, then number), would yield a different result than your example

Comment: Hi, Mathias, what would be the result, could please explain?

Comment: Sorting these values by first letter has no effect on the set you've described (they all start with `a`), sorting by numbers you would get `a01` first (`01` is `1`, the smallest number in the set), then `ab9` (9 is the second-smallest), then `ab10` etc.

Comment: Ahh, "first by letter", not "by first letter", my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Sort-Object` cmdlet can take one or more scriptblocks as its Property argument. First argument should remove all the digits at the end, then remove all non-digits and cast to an integer:

```
$a |Sort-Object {"$_" -replace '\d',''},{("$_" -replace '\D','') -as [int]}
```

- `\d` is regex for digits
- `\D` is regex for anything that *isn't* digits

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, Mathias! I didn't realize the sort-object can take two expressions separated by comma. 
I refined just a little bit to save some typing.
$a | Sort-Object {"$_" -replace '\d'},{[int]("$_" -replace '\D')}

Comment: @LiangCui You can also combine expressions and property names if need be: `$a |Sort-Object Length,{[int]("$_"-replace'\D','')}`

Comment: uh... got it.  I am so new to stackoverflow. My bad for the inconvenience.